# Tour not supporting a new album

Tags: terminology

What would the term be for an artist's tour where they are playing music they have not recorded, nor will they plan to?

An example, Zakk Wylde is (or just finished) a tour where he is playing an all-Black Sabbath set.  I don't believe there is a studio album that features these songs arranged by Zakk Wylde as he performed them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just by intuition, I would call that a *tribute tour*, by analogy to *[tribute band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribute_act)*, which is a group that exclusively (or nearly exclusively) performs the music of a specific other group as a "tribute" to that group.  A quick Google search shows that the term "tribute tour" does exist, and is used in the manner described.  I'd imagine you would only use the *tribute tour* terminology if the band performing is not itself exclusively a tribute band --otherwise you'd just call it a tribute band on tour.

(A band that performs all covers, but not by a single group is a *cover band*, but there's no analogous "cover tour" term.)

Comment: I never herd of a band big as Black Label Society doing a tribute tour.One set of Black Sabbath music in the concert would be a tribute. Strange with Ozzy getting ready to release a new album and the reformed Black Sabbath tour ending not too long ago.